# Substitute for EasClientDeviceInformation() in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows

In one of our projects on Win-RT targeting Windows 8.1 , we had used EasClientDeviceInformation() to get the client device information. But, now we want our app to be working on windows 10. So is there anything else that we could be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not change your code at all. EasClientDeviceInformation API is available on Windows 10 and you can use it in universal windows app and it would work on both Desktop and Phone. [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation) for this API lists the detail.